# Operation Contract Serialization Error With Entity Framework 6.0 and WCF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

In my C# app I am trying to send a request through an intermediary DLL to add data to QuickBooks. The intermediary DLL, based off of a setting, sends the item add request through a WCF service. The service project is using Operation Contracts for all methods housed within it. It does not have any data contract/data members.

This works find for invoices and other transactions. However, when adding an item, I receive this error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> Additional information: Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.QBLookUp_A96F53AD8DA6F21651FEF0B25078616AB4989DA745EE06E345D365196574CE0F'
>   with data contract name
>   'QBLookUp_A96F53AD8DA6F21651FEF0B25078616AB4989DA745EE06E345D365196574CE0F:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

Looking around here on Stack Overflow, I ran into several threads that suggested to turn off proxy creation in my EF Model to get around this issue. So I inserted this bit of code into the constructor in my EF project:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

However, when I turn off proxy creation, I run into two new problems:

A) Various bits of data do not show up in my C# app. This data is supplied to the app by Entity Framework.

B) I receive this error when trying to save the item via the WCF service:

> Additional information: Object graph for type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[EFModel.Item, EFModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled

This leads me to the following conclusion - I need to have proxy creation enabled in order for my application to work, and at the same time I may be doing something wrong with my service.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could change to get things working?

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally comes when you try to serialize data which cannot be done by WCF. Why the first answer works fine for some casea because if you will turn off the proxy creation WCF will know which data need to be serialized if you mark your class with DataContract attribute if proxy would be on then proxy classes will be created on FLY and WCF can not serialize those classes.

IF you are using entity framework so I guess you would have been using lambda expression to retrieve those records from db in your client. Since WCF does not serialize lambda Expression by default so you can not pass lambda expression to querying those records from client.(Why - since WCF is used for SOA architecture and service is generic so that any kind of client(JAVA,C++ etc) can consume this service and lambda expression is specific to some language. If it will implement this feature in WCF then it will violate the rule of SOA architecture).

If you still want to use lambda expression then you need to create dynamic lambda expression. But that is not better way to implement because client will be bound to use in that way. Try not to use lambda expression in client.

creating Dynamic Lambda expression is given in this link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resorted to using a DTO for all of the objects that EF was creating proxies for that which WCF could not handle. It was a bit of extra code but the results worked out nicely, as I am still able to use proxies and lazy loading.